# Project Euler - Largest Palindrome #4 Python

Tags: python

I'm new to python and decided it would be a good idea to improve my coding (in general) by doing some of the challenges on project Euler. I'm currently stuck on problem 4 and i'm not sure what is going wrong (for those not in the know, problem 4 is as follows):

> A palindromic number reads the same both ways.
>
> The largest palindrome made from the product of two 2-digit numbers is 9009 = 91 x 99.

Find the largest palindrome made from the product of two 3-digit numbers.

```
x, y = 999, 999
palindrome = []
while True:
    palindrome = [i for i in str(x * y)]
    r_palindrome = palindrome[::-1]
    if palindrome == r_palindrome:
        break
    else:
        y -= 1
        if y < 100: 
            y = x
            x -= 1
print x, y, palindrome
```

I seem to get the answer `987 * 286 = 282282` which feels awfully low. 
Can someone explain the best way of doing this and what my current code is doing wrong rather than just a simple "here is the code" answer please.

Comment: Why are you checking for the product being even? Am I missing something?

Comment: I get "982 869 ['8', '5', '3', '3', '5', '8']" when I run this.

Comment: Sorry missed an equals when editing it. Umm not really sure, perhaps my logic is horribly off

Comment: After some changes I now get 580085 with 995*583

Comment: So have you tried debugging it with print statements?

Comment: I think in general my logic is flawed. My idea was to decrease one of the variables (y in this case) and times it by x. This would result in calculations like x *998... x*997...x*996...x*y-- while y >100. If y then breaks this, you would decrease x by 1 and start again looking for the largest palindrome.

Comment: Your code doesn't do what you think it does, but your first step should be to debug. Set x and y to 15, `print "x = {}, y = {}".format(x, y)` on every iteration and you'll see

Comment: @GreenAsJade my super quick attempt gives 906609 from 993*913

Comment: I was wrong, deleted my comment - pokes answer is right :)

Comment: Yeah, brute force seems to be giving: (906609, 993, 913)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting at `x = 999` and `y = 999` and then decrementing only `y` until you restart with a decremented `x` and a reset `y` does not guarantee you that you will hit the largest palindrome first.

Just think of the following example: Let’s imagine a different requirement for the product (to not spoil the palindrome result here). Imagine you starting with `x = 999` and then you reach to `y = 101` until you hit the first “valid” result.

In your case, you would accept `999 * 101 = 100899` as the largest result. But there may actually be a different solution `998 * 998 = 996004` which you never looked at but is obviously much larger.

So you need to change how you decide when to stop looking and know that you reached the largest number.

---

Btw. as a general hint for Project Euler: Especially the first problems can be easily solved with brute force (i.e. trying out every possible solution). While this will probably not give you a satisfying feeling that you solved the problem in a smart way, it does give you an idea on how to get there. You can always work out a better solution then, but keep in mind that Project Euler has actually *a lot* problems which are completely impossible using brute force anyway, so you have enough to worry about later ;)

For this particular problem, you could write a list comprehension that would give you all palindromes and then get the maximum of it. That’s a one-liner; it’s very inefficient but for this particularly small input domain, it’s fast enough to still give you an answer instantly:

```
max([(x * y, x, y) for x in range(100, 1000) for y in range(100, 1000) if str(x * y) == str(x * y)[::-1]])
```

Comment: if you add `(x*y) % 11 == 0` it makes it significantly faster.  Palindromes are all divisible by 11.

Comment: @crazyPen The code runs in less than a second, that’s certainly fast enough for a Project Euler problem.

Comment: sure but adding that check reduces its time from 0.7sec to 0.2sec

Answer (score 0):

OK, just to find the solution, let's use brute force:

```
>>> prod = itertools.product(range(999,99,-1),range(999,99,-1))
>>> palindromes = [(x*y,x,y) for x,y in prod  if str(x*y) == str(x*y)[::-1]]
>>> max(palindromes, key=lambda t: t[0])
(906609, 993, 913)
```

Took a bit of time, but at least we have the answer. I've worked out a solution that works very quickly, and I think it takes the essense of what you were trying to achieve:

```
>>> x = 999
>>> palindromes = []
>>> floor = 99
>>> while x > floor:
...     for i in range(x,floor,-1):
...         product = x*i
...         candidate = str(product)
...         if candidate == candidate[::-1]:
...             palindromes.append((product,x,i))
...             floor = i
...             break
...     x -= 1
... 
>>> palindromes
[(580085, 995, 583), (906609, 993, 913), (886688, 968, 916), (888888, 962, 924)]
>>>
```

Essentially, this updates the floor with the lowest number that last gave us a palindrome. We know we don't have to look lower than that each time.